# Hosting a Discord Bot on a Root-Server

Tags: discord, discord.js, hosting

I wanted to host a Discord Bot on my friends Root Server and did everything the same way I did on my Computer. (Download Node js and Visual Studio Code and start setting it up). Unfortunately the Root Server is blocking some files, so I can't just do it the same way as I did on my computer. My question now is, is there any other way to host the bot on the Root Server or do I need to start looking for other hosting options?

Comment: Which OS is running on your root server?

Comment: Windows but it's not activated

Comment: Windows with GUI or just the cli?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but how can i found out what i have?

Comment: GUI = graphical user interface. CLI = command line interface. The CLI-version of windows is just the cmd window and the "GUI-version" is the windows, that 99% of people use

Comment: But since you installed VS Code on the server, I guess you're running the "standard" windows

Comment: Yeah it's the GUI Version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237831/discussion-between-toasty-and-i-need-help).